# Kotlin, WorkManager scheduled repeatedly once in a week

Tags: android, kotlin, background-task

I have an app where user can scan details from his device and send details via https to my backend service so I can evaluate his data and send other data back to his mobile device.

Now I need to implement background task which would do previously mentioned scan once in a week, let's say on friday even when the application is not running. I don't want to send back to device any data if scan is run in background task not from user directly. I just need to send data from device to service.

I would like to choose the best solution which seems like WorkManager with periodic work request (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest). However I have few questions.

1. Let's say I would like to make a scan every friday. Only constraint is that user has to be connected to the internet. If user install my application and execute it on monday I would set the repeat interval for 5 days and flex interval for 1 day. So background work should be executed last day which is friday. But after this background scan, period should change from 5 days to 7 days, so it can execute every next friday. How can I make this change? Should I run OneTime background work which run scan after 5 days and create repeated background task with 7 days period?
2. If user is not connected to internet all friday, is it gonna take another period (7 days in this case) since next execute or will it execute on saturday? If not on saturday, what should I do to run it on saturday?
3. If user is not connected to internet for half of friday, it is going to execute my background work on friday afternoon with 7 days interval and 1 flex day interval. However since the user wasn't connected for half day, next background work will be execute from friday afternoon to saturday midday? Or will it execute only in friday just like previous work? If not how can I prevent this behaviour?
4. If Work Manager can't ensure, that background task will be executed on friday, what should I use than. I think that one day is a quite huge interval and it shouldn't be such problem, right?

I am grateful for every opinion and advice.

Comment: `WorkRequest.Builder` has a `setInitialDelay` function: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#setInitialDelay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: Thank you, this should solve question number one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that time I put here the question I have gained some experience so I am going to type some advice for users with same questions.

If you want to proceed background task once per several days, I recommend you to set period interval for one day and check if last time that background work was processed was already your expected period. For example if you want period once per week, set the period for one day. In every day background work check if last work was before 7 days. With this condition if background is not processed after 7 days, it will be started after 8 days or 9 days but not after 14 days as it would be if period was set on 7 days.

I also recommend you to check battery in your mobile settings, find your application and make sure, that your application will no be forced stop due to battery optimalization. Because force stop will also kill your background work.